# Build the data bytes to query a contract with the api state_call

Tags: smart-contract, pallet-contracts, contracts, query

I would like to use the `rpc call` to query a contract.

I try to use the method `"call"` from the endpoint `"state"` with the first parameter `"ContractsApi_call"` but I am not able to fully build the second parameter (data).

Here an example:

[image]

In this example the data bytes are:

```
0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d1200ccd8b1a8f39b6d1d69463f5c4281bf9ec5ddfd80eedbba0ee221a30a02a600000000000000000000000000000000000020ba48eafe0c313233
```

From my understanding the data bytes are decomposed like this:

```
  - the origin address :  d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d
  - the contract address: 1200ccd8b1a8f39b6d1d69463f5c4281bf9ec5ddfd80eedbba0ee221a30a02a6
  - the missing piece: 00000000000000000000000000000000000020 
  - the selector of the method to call : ba48eafe
  - the args of the method: 0c313233
```

I would like to understand how is build the missing piece (00000000000000000000000000000000000020), in particular last part(20).

Anyone could help me to understand?

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the answer and I put it there if it can help anyone else.

I need to create the following struct:

ContractCall {
origin : AccountId,
dest : AccountId,
value : Balance,
gas_limit : Option,
storage_deposit_limit : Option,
data: Vec,
}
In my case the data is the concatenation of:

- the selector of the method: [u8;4]
- the args of the method: Vec

and encode the whole struct.